# Norm of function as $p$ goes to zero

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^1( [0,1])$. Show that

a) the limit of $||f||_p$ exists as $p \to 0^+$
b) If the measure of the set of points where $f$ is zero is positive, i.e. $ m( \{x\in [0,1] \mid f(x) = 0 \} ) > 0$, then the above limit is zero

I am trying to figure out how a) makes any sense since the function $f$ is in $L^1$. For $p \to 0 ^+$, does it mean that $ ( \int |f|^p) ^{1/p}  < \infty$ ?

Comment: This is a well known result and it has been answered  on this site before. The limit is $e^{\int \log |f(x)|dx}$.

Comment: Let $A=\{|f|\le 1\},B= \{|f|> 1\}.$ If $0<p<1,$ then

$$\int_0^1 |f|^p = \int_A |f|^p + \int_B |f|^p \le 1\cdot m(A) + \int_B |f|^1 <\infty.$$